# Use multiprocess in class with python version == 3.9

Tags: python, class, multiprocessing

I am trying to use multiprocessing in a class in the following code:

```
class test:

    def __init__(self):
        return

    global calc_corr
    @staticmethod
    def calc_corr(idx, df1, df2):
        arr1 = df1.iloc[idx:idx+5, :].values.flatten('F')
        arr2 = df2.iloc[idx:idx+5, :].values.flatten('F')
        df_tmp = pd.DataFrame([arr1, arr2]).T
        df_tmp.dropna(how='any', inplace=True)
        corr = df_tmp.corr().iloc[0, 1]
        return corr

    def aa(self):
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(100, 6)))
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(100, 6)))
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            results = [executor.submit(calc_corr, (i, df1, df2)) for i in range(20)]
            for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
                print(f.result())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = test()
    t.aa()
```

I am using a `@staticmethod` because it is not related to the class, it's just a computing tool. But using it raises the following error when running the code:

```
D:\anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/jonas/Desktop/728_pj/test.py
concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 245, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'staticmethod' object
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jonas\Desktop\728_pj\test.py", line 31, in <module>
    t.aa()
  File "C:\Users\jonas\Desktop\728_pj\test.py", line 26, in aa
    print(f.result())
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 438, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 390, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 245, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'staticmethod' object

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is somehow caused by the `staticmethod` being declared as global. When I tried removing the `global calc_corr` line and changing
`results = [executor.submit(calc_corr, (i, df1, df2)) for i in range(20)]` to
`results = [executor.submit(self.calc_corr, i, df1, df2) for i in range(20)]` it seemed to work fine. I'm not actually sure of the reason what you wrote doesn't work but hopefully this will.

Note: Removing the tuple for the arguments is unrelated to this issue but was causing another issue afterwards.

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate your help, it works now. The reason is that I wasn't using self.calc_corr to call this method but calc_corr instead. So there is a 'undefined function' error. That's the reason why I add 'global calc_corr' to call it. It seems like I make a mistake when calling a method inside the class, which is using self.method whether it is staticmethod or not.

Comment: yes, I remove the tuple afterwords. I thought tuple is a right way to input multiple parameters but seems that I was wrong. Just enter the parameters one by one is enough.

Comment: Yup, the function is defined using an asterisk like `def foo(*bar):`. This means that any arguments it is given are put in `bar` as a list, so you can give it inputs like you would a normal function with any number of parameters. Anyway, make sure to mark the question as answered if this solved the problem.